# ConcurrentLinkedQueue Code Explanation

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, queue

http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Open-Source-Library/7-JDK/java/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.java.htm

The above is the source code of ConcurrentLinkedQueue.
I am not able to understand one condition.

How the condition **(p == q)** will come in the below snippet code from offer method

```
  public boolean offer(E e) {
        checkNotNull(e);
        final Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(e);

        for (Node<E> t = tail, p = t;;) {
            Node<E> q = p.next;
            if (q == null) {
                // p is last node
                if (p.casNext(null, newNode)) {
                    // Successful CAS is the linearization point
                    // for e to become an element of this queue,
                    // and for newNode to become "live".
                    if (p != t) // hop two nodes at a time
                        casTail(t, newNode);  // Failure is OK.
                    return true;
                }
                // Lost CAS race to another thread; re-read next
            }
            else if (p == q)
                // We have fallen off list.  If tail is unchanged, it
                // will also be off-list, in which case we need to
                // jump to head, from which all live nodes are always
                // reachable.  Else the new tail is a better bet.
                p = (t != (t = tail)) ? t : head;
            else
                // Check for tail updates after two hops.
                p = (p != t && t != (t = tail)) ? t : q;
        }
    }
```

and also what does the author mean by "We have fallen off List"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` allows concurrent modification of the internal list while traversing it. This implies that the node you are looking at could have been removed concurrently. To detect such situations the next pointer of a removed node is changed to point to itself. Look at `updateHead` (L302) for details.

Comment: @Holger : Can you explain how does the remove method of concurrentlinkedqueue work? Because when I tried understanding it in multi threaded environments it seems to not work that I am missing something

Comment: public boolean remove(Object o) {
        if (o == null) return false;
        Node<E> pred = null;
        for (Node<E> p = first(); p != null; p = succ(p)) {
            E item = p.item;
            if (item != null &&
                o.equals(item) &&
                p.casItem(item, null)) {
                Node<E> next = succ(p);
                if (pred != null && next != null)
                    pred.casNext(p, next);
                return true;
            }
            pred = p;
        }
        return false;
    }

Comment: @Aarish: what do you mean with “it seems to not work”?

Comment: @Holger I tried dry running it on paper for removals by concurrent threads ex for list like A -> B -> C -> D-> E  and thread 1 removing C , thread2 removing D. In this case I don't see B's next pointing to E finally if the two threads switches the execution going with the above code. In both cases , if (pred != null && next != null) will not get executed as C or  D will be null. So I am just wondering how does node's next gets set under concurrent modifications

Comment: @Aarish: setting the item to `null` doesn’t set the next pointer to `null`. In this code, next is never set to `null`. It seems you are confusing items and nodes.

Answer (score 2):

The condition asks the question "Is the current node the same as the next node?"

If so, you've fallen off list ( documentation in line. )

The basic outline of steps is:

1. create a new node for the offered data.
2. walk the list to find the last node
3. insert new node as new tail.

The other parts of the if statement are handling concurrent modification issues.

To better understand what's going on, read Node.casTail() and the casNext()

Comment: "The condition asks the question "Is the current node the same as the next node?"" Isn't it that is the main question because it is not very obvious why next node we have got using p.next will equal to p.

Comment: It's one of the conditions that can occur because of concurrent modification of the list.

Comment: @mawia are you still unclear on anything, if not can you mark an accepted answer or clarify what you think is missing so i can improve the answer?